# How to publish custom dropdown with values to Devops workitem form using ADO Extension

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I have developed a group extension and able to publish it to Devops but I want to publish a custom dropdown to Devops workitem form. I have followed the below document but not able to publish the custom control.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/custom-control?view=azure-devops

The attached picture shows custom group, where a html page is getting loaded as iframe , I want to save the state of the dropdown value when the workitem gets saved but in my case whenever the workitem is opened my custom group is loading as iframe from initial state

Can someone please help me with ,how to publish a custom dropdown to Devops org using ADO Extension.

[image: Valid XHTML]

Thanks in advance.
[Manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43gAS.png)
[Devops form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6Wsl.png)

Comment: Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

We could use the Cross-platform CLI for Azure DevOps (tfx-cli) to publish your extension to the Visual Studio Marketplace.

1. Create PAT, we need ensure the PAT have Account: 'All accessible organizations'.
2. Install TFX CLI, you could open a Command Prompt and enter `npm i -g tfx-cli`.
3. Create a publisher via the cmd `tfx extension publisher create`
4. Publish the extension via the command line `tfx extension publish`, if your extension has already been published, we can add the `--rev-version` command line option to automatically increment the patch version of your extension.

We could refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/publish/command-line?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts) for more details. Also, we could refer to this doc to [package and publish extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/publish/overview?view=azure-devops).

**Update1**

If you want add dropdown in your extension, we should use `pickList`, you could refer to Azure DevOps task, these tasks are [open source on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks), we could refer the task [Azure Power Shell](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzurePowerShellV5/task.json#L100) to add dropdown.

In the vss-extension.json file, it should looks like this

```
{
            "name": "{dropdown field name}",
            "type": "pickList",
            "label": "{label}",
            "required": false,
            "defaultValue": "{default Value}",
            "options": {
                {dropdown content}
            },
            "helpMarkDown": "{helpMarkDown link}"
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Could you please help with how the vss-extension.json file and Html file should look like to publish custom dropdown

Comment: Hi @AnilKumar, I have updated the answer, you could check it and then kindly share the result here. Thanks

Comment: Hi, i am following these steps 
1.installed node.js 
2. npm init -y 
3. npm install -g tfx-cli
4. npm install vss-web-extension-sdk --save
5. added vss-exension.json (PFA img)
6. added index.html (PFA Img)
7.  npx tfx extension create
8. uploading to market place
9. Installing in org

i have added images of my vss-extension.json , index.html ,folder structure and customization page. please correct me if any more steps to be needed,

Comment: Hi @Vito Lui, Thank you for all your inputs and help. I am following the same steps which you told to use Cross-platform CLI but i am not able to see any picklist control in my workitem form UI. i have added images of my manifest file and devops form. please let me know if should add any other scripts. Thank you – Anil Kumar